# Convert `# Headline' to actual html headlines using regex

Tags: javascript, html, web

Hi im trying to make my own small markdown script using regex for a personal project.
I managed to convert the following to html headlines

> # Welcome
> This is just some example text that will still do it for the context
>
> ## Details
> just some more text that no one cares about

Im able to convert the headlines using this regex: `/#{1,6}\s.+/g`
It will look like in the image
My Problem is that its converting it all to <h1> tags, tho i dont know how to get it to work using <h1>, <h2>, ...

im using a simple .replace statement with the following values:
`[/#{1,6}\s.+/g, '<h1 class="doc-title">$&</h1>'.replace("#", "")]`

[Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNOJb.png)

im using a simple .replace statement with the following values:
`[/#{1,6}\s.+/g, '<h1 class="doc-title">$&</h1>'.replace("#", "")]`

I tried many different things i found but none worked or was about something else

Comment: You are going to have to somehow count the amounf of `#` symbols and spit out the appropriate tag.

Comment: Maybe you can group the '#'s like (#{1,6}) and get size of this group by back referencing the group in replace method's second argument.

Comment: Use a callback function for your replacement (details on how that works, see the duplicate). Inside your function, you have access to the matched value - so you can then get the `length` of that string, and with that determine what `X` you have to put into `<hX>...</hX>`

Comment: @CBroe idk if this works with my case. Im not trying to convert a existing tag into another one. Im trying to turn "# test1" into <h1>test1</h1> but i dont really get it how to do it. i tried it a lot but just couldnt get it to work

Comment: Yes, I got what you want. Your expression needs to capture the `#` and the `test1` part separately. In your callback function, you then access that first captured match, and get its `length`. That would be 1 for `#`, 2 for `##`, etc. - that is the value you need to put after the `h` in your headline element tags. And the second match, the `test1` part, then gets concatenated in between the two tags.